# What is the minimum weighting trials to be made with a two pan scale to find the lighter marble?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The puzzle is as follows:

> Over a table there are three bags with marbles, on the first one there are 100 blue marbles, on the second one there are 100 red marbles and on the third one there are 100 green marbles. All the marbles inside the bags are in equal weight, except two of them whose weight is slightly less from the others and identical, which are on different bags. Considering all of this, How many weighing trials at minimum must be made by using a two pan scale to find with certainty those two mysterious lighter marbles?

The choices given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{11 trials}\\
2.&\textrm{8 trials}\\
3.&\textrm{9 trials}\\
4.&\textrm{10 trials}\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly how to solve this problem, my best effort goes as this:

Assuming that those bags fit in the two pan scale (hence marbles are sufficiently small) then you put in the left pan one bag and in the other the other bag.

The best thing that it can happen is that right off the bat one bag is heavier than the other because it contains the heavier marbles. The worst thing is that they are equal in weight because they both contain those mysterious lighter marbles. But either one way or another. Assuming we know beforehand there are two marbles whose weight is less than the others and those two are in two separate bags then this means that if those two bags weight the same, then those two bags contains the marbles we're looking for. While the other bag has the heavier marbles.

**All of this account for one weighing trial.**

Now that we discriminated those bags, we know our two bags which contains the lighter marbles we split them in groups of 50. This accounts for four groups.

Assuming that we do not mix those, we put those two groups in one pan and the other two in the other pan.

The worst that can happen is that they are even, and we still cannot tell on which side there are the ligther msrbles.

Thus a new weighing trial is needed.

**This accounts for a second trial.**

In the next trial, we switch the groups by fixing two groups. After doing this, the scale will reveal which side is the lighter one. Thus the heavier marbles can now be returned back to the group of the marbles which do weight more.

**This accounts for our third trial.**

We repeat the cycle again. But now we have 100 marbles remaining, as the other 100 went back with their set of heavier marbles. Thus, we split those in 4 groups of 25.

Assuming that it happens the same as before, we can't tell the different first, so a new weighing trial is needed.

**This accounts for our fourth trial.**

We repeat the weighing trial, switching the groups, and we know for sure 50 marbles are heavier and the other 50 must contain the lighter marbles.

**This accounts for the fifth trial.**

We now have 50 marbles whose weight must contain those two marbles. We again repeat the cycle. In this case we cannot divide 25 by 4. Remember that all the time we are keeping track on which side belongs to which bag, so we have took care not to mix the groups. So we use one of these groups of 25 (and save the other for later) from which we know it contains a ligther marble. But because 25 cannot be split in two. We take out from that group a marble, and we have two groups of 12.

We perform a new weighing trial. The best thing it can happen is both sides are even and we got our lighter marble. The worst thing is that we need a new weighing trial.

**This accounts for a sixth trial.**

We collect the heavier marbles as this was revealed by the scale plus the marble what we took out first and we end up with 12 ones from which we don't know where is the mysterios marble and perform a new weighing trial. This time splitting in six and six.

Again we assume that the worst thing that can happen is that we are still unable to know where is the mysterious marble.

From those we know that six are heavier as the scale revealed this to us by tilting it to one side.

**This account for a seventh trial.**

We now have six from which we don't know where is the ligther marble. We split them in groups of 3 and 3 and perform a new weighing trial, from it we do know the heavier ones.

**This accounts for the eight trial.**

Now it comes finally our last 3 marbles. From these we must take out one. In any case it will be revealed which is ligther. If the scale is even, then the one which we took out is the lighter. If one side is heavier the other resting in the other pan is the ligther one, which belongs to one bag.

Remember that we saved one group from before performing the sixth trial. Thus as we required 3 steps to discover which marble was the ligther one, this adds to the already weighing trials that we accounted.

This means $8+3=11$

Thus I conclude that at minimum we do need $11$ weighing trials for that, or choice 1. But of course, I could be overlooking something.

Can someone please check my logic?. I am not sure if it can done in less steps or in a different way, but to my understanding this is the most logical way to do it.

Thus can someone help me here?.

Comment: How do you fix two groups? Its possible you switch the bags with same weight and gain nothing from this 3rd troal. “This accounts for a second trial.

In the next trial, we switch the groups by fixing two groups. After doing this, the scale will reveal which side is the lighter one. Thus the heavier marbles can now be returned back to the group of the marbles which do weight more.”

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it in $10$ total weighings, which as saulspatz pointed out, is optimal.

**First weighing:** all of one color vs all of another color.  From this you know the colors of the two lightweight or "bad" marbles.  (BTW this weighing reduces the no. of possibilities from $3 \times 10^4$ to $10^4$ which is the best you can do.)

For the rest, lets assume the two colors with bad marbles are Red and Green.

At this point, what saulspatz's "oracle" argument shows is that if you never mix the two colors in a subsequent weighing, you cannot do better than $5$ more per color, or $11$ total.  So the key is indeed to having further weighing(s) with both colors.

Let $R$ be a fixed subset of $81$ red marbles, and $R'$ be the remaining $19$ red marbles.  Similarly let $G$ be a fixed subset of $81$ green marbles, and $G'$ be the remaining $19$ green marbles.

**Second weighing:** $R$ vs $G'$ plus $81-19 = 62$ blue ("good") marbles, so that there are $81$ on each side.  We have $3$ possibilities:

- The most common case is $R < G' + B$.  In this case we know:

  - The bad red marble is in $R$, which we can find out using $4$ more weighings  because $3^4 = 81$.
  - The bad green marble is in $G$, which we can also find out using $4$ more weighings.
  - So the total no. of weighings $= 1+1+4+4 = 10$.
- The least common, and also easiest case is $R > G' + B$.  In this case we know:

  - The bad red marble is in $R'$, and we can find it using $3$ more weighings coz $3^3 > 19$.
  - The bad green marble is in $G'$, another $3$ weighings.
  - So the total no. of weighings $= 8$.
- The last case, conceptually the most complicated, is $R = G' + B$.  In this case, the sets containing the bad marbles can be (i) $R$ and $G'$, or, (ii) $R'$ and $G$.

Luckily, we have enough leeway to "waste" the third weighing to find out which of (i) or (ii) is true.

**Third weighing (for $R = G' + B$ case):**  Simply weight $R$ vs $81$ blue marbles to see if $R$ contains a bad marble.  Since the blues are all good, there can be only two outcomes:

- If $R$ weighs less, then we have case (i) where we know the bad marbles are in $R$ and $G'$.  The one in $R$ can be found by $4$ more weighings, and the one in $G'$ can be found by $3$ more, for a total of $1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 3 = 10$ weighings.
- If $R$ weighs equal with the blues, then we have case (ii) which is symmetric.

BTW, visualizing the $100 \times 100$ possibilities (after the first weighing) as a $100\times 100$ grid helped me solve this problem.

Comment: Your answer of 10 weighing trials doesn't match with the official answer in my workbook which states 11 weighing trials. Could it be that what you made is a different interpretation?. I don't understand **why** $81$ means that it can be weighed in $4$ trials?. Can you **please** explain this part because I don't get it.

Comment: Excellent!  I couldn't see how to exploit the blue marbles.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell If you had $3$ red marbles, one of which is known to be light, you could locate it in one weighing.  Weight two of them against each other.  If they balance, the third marble is the light one.  If they don't it's the one in the pan that weights less.  What if you have $9$ marbles?  Split them into $3$ groups of $3$, and use the above procedure to locate the group of $3$ with the light marble.  One more weighing will locate the light marble, so for $3^2$ marbles, we need $2$ weighings. ...

Comment: For $3^3$ marbles, we split them into $3$ groups of $9$, use one weighing to locate the light group, and $2$ more to find the light marble.  And so on.  Have you considered the possibility that the "official answer" is wrong?

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for help with explaining!  Chris - if this is supposed to be a simple 1-minute multiple choice in a quiz, then certainly whoever set the exam got it wrong (or had an unstated assumption that any pan can contain only 1 color of marbles).  it takes <1 min to get a 11-weighing solution, but it took me many minutes to get the 10-weighing solution.  BTW you can read more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_puzzle

Comment: @antkam Try this.  Suppose one bag contains a heavy marble and one bag contains a light one.  Show that $11$ weighings are necessary and sufficient to identify the two bad marbles.  Necessity is easy.  Sufficiency took me several days.  Now I'm going to see if I can analyze the general case of $n$ marbles in each bag.

Comment: @saulspatz - Ooh, that sounds like a really good puzzle!  You might even want to post it so more people can try.  Great that the weekend is coming up and I have nothing planned!  :D In return, a few months ago I posted [this puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799849/difficult-coin-weighing-puzzle-14-coins-1-fake-heavier-or-lighter-3-pre-det) and it was quite popular so maybe you'd enjoy it too.

Comment: @antkam If I posted it, it would be on puzzling.se, but that's not a site I like much, and I rarely go there.  I was thinking that if I can't deal will the general case, I'll post it here.

Comment: @saulspatz - my own puzzle above got a comment saying it's more appropriate in puzzling.se, but it never gathered enough (5) votes to be closed, and TBH this kind of "transgression" happens all the time in math.se esp. tags recreational-math & puzzle. e.g. [this 8-month-old](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743564/another-coins-weighing-puzzle) is another great weighing puzzle. BTW, you might enjoy knowing that while driving and thinking about your puzzle just now, i missed an exit and had to stay hungry for 3 extra minutes before i could pick up dinner takeout. :D

Comment: @saulpatz - I think I have a solution to your puzzle, and it starts with partitioning each color into sets of 81 and 19, and then weighing all 3 pairs of 81 vs 81. Is that similar to your solution? I still think you should post it on math.se and tag it puzzle. That way there is more space to discuss. :)

Comment: @saulspatz - sorry mistyped your name in previous comment!

Comment: @antkam I didn't get pinged because of the typo; I wasn't ignoring you.  Your solution sounds simpler than mine.  I'll have to try to finish it form that hint.  I'm still trying to figure out the general rule.

Comment: @antkam Slick.  Much better than mine.  Do you think $108$ coins per bag is the most you can do in $11$ weighings?  I think that, with your algorithm to build on, I can write an MSE post later today.

Comment: @saulspatz (No worry about the delay - it was entirely my fault with my typo!)  Yeah, my approaches - to your puzzle, and also to the OP puzzle - both generalize to 108 marbles, but no more than that.  One thing I did wonder about your puzzle: I didnt use any weighing that could have put both heavy + light marbles on the same side of the scale, since it's unspecified what would happen.  BUT if we knew what would happen (e.g. together they equal 2 good marbles?) I wonder if we can handle more marbles?  Hard to imagine, since 108 is such a specially nice number, but still...

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can't be done in fewer than $10$ weighings.  There are $3\cdot10^2\cdot10^2$ possible answers.  Each weighing gives $3$ possible answers: the pans balance, the left-hand pan is heavier, or the right-hand pan is heavier.  $9$ weighings have only $3^9<3\cdot10^4$ possible outcomes, so they can't reliably distinguish between all possible answers.

I believe that it can't be done in $10$ weighings, either, but I can't say my argument is truly a rigorous proof.

To begin with, it seems like weighing one bag against another must be the way to start.  This eliminates $100$ marbles in one shot, and we can't expect to do any better.  Let's say that the blue marbles are all standard, and there's one light red and one light green.  Then it seems to me that we can just weigh the red and green marbles separately.  If after the first weighing, and oracle tells you which is the light green marble, that doesn't help you find the light red marble.  Now $3^4<100$, so we'd need $5$ weighings at least to find the light red marble.  In the absence of an oracle, we also need $5$ weighings to find the light green marble, so $1+5+5=11$ weighing in all.

There are a couple of points where the reasoning seems a bit iffy to me, but I'm going to post it anyway.  Maybe someone can clean it up.

**EDIT**

As antkam's answer shows, the above reasoning is false, and $10$ weighings are possible.  I'm not going to delete or edit the post, however, because antkam's answer refers to it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I consulted with the original source and verified that the answers sheet and your answer as well mine check with the right answer. It would be nice to know why did $9$ weighings account for $3^9$ possible outcomes? and also from **why** there are $3\cdot 10^2 \cdot 10^2$ possible answers? I don't understand this part from your answer.

Comment: There are $3$ possible choices for the bag with all standard marbles.  For each of the other $2$ bags there are $10^2$ choices for which marble is light.  That gives $3\cdot 10^2 \cdot 10^2$ possible solutions.  As I explained in the answer, the two pan balance only gives $3$ answers, so in $9$ weighings, you can only get $3^9$ sequences of answers.  These can't possible distinguish between all possible solutions.

Comment: [Here](https://www.smartdraw.com/decision-tree/) is a discussion of a decision tree.  It's a binary tree, because at every stage we ask a yes/no question.  In our case, we ask a question with $3$ possible answers, so the tree spreads out as a factor of $3$ instead of $2$.  After one weighing we have $3$ leaves, after $2$ we have $9$ leaves, after $9$ we have $3^9$ leaves.  But at the end we have to announce the solution.  If there are more solutions than leaves, some leaf is consistent with more than one solution, and we can't know for sure which one it is.